# Keep observations only overlapped id in two data sets in R?

Tags: r, sorting

I have two data sets. Suppose data A and data B and two data sets have id variables.
In two data sets, I want to remove ids which are not overlapped. In other words, I want to keep ids which are exist in two data sets.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether you want to do this separately for each data set or if you like to merge both data sets into one data set (or data frame). You can try this with `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- data.frame(id = c("A", "B", "C"),
                  var1 = c(1,2,3))
df2 <- data.frame(id = c("A", "C", "E"),
                  var2 = c(4,5,6))

# matching ids in data frame 1
dplyr::semi_join(df1, df2, "id")

>   id var1
> 1  A    1
> 2  C    3

# matching ids in data frame 2
dplyr::semi_join(df2, df1, "id")

>   id var1
> 1  A    4
> 2  C    5

# merge column from both data frames
# matching the id
dplyr::inner_join(df1, df2, "id")

>   id var1 var2
> 1  A    1    4
> 2  C    3    5
```